# JSON value not showing with getJSON function

Tags: jquery, json

I really need help on reading the JSON data on this URL:

http://www.cloudspokes.com/members/ferbie12/past_challenges.json

I am trying to use `--disable-web-security` on google chrome to solve cross domain issues.
here is a code that I wrote to read a simple value on the JSON.

```
$.getJSON("www.cloudspokes.com/members/ferbie12/past_challenges.json",function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(){
        var test = data.attributes.type;
        $('p#success').append(test);
    });
});
```

it won't show anything on the browser.
really appreciate the help.

update:
I also tried using these codes. still no results.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "www.cloudspokes.com/members/ferbie12/past_challenges.json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(){
            var test = data.attributes.type;
            $('p#success').append(test);
        });
    itemAddCallback(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $("#success").html(xhr.responseText);   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the protocol-part of the URI

After fixing it use the following to iterate over the items:

```
$.each(data, function(index,item){
    var test = item.attributes.type;
    $('p#success').append(test);
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for answering... found a way around it... it seems that the cross domain issue is still not fixed with the "--disable-web-security"...

also your answer helped me... thanks :D